# Как скопировать данные из одной таблицы в другую MySQL?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

имеются две таблицы с разными полями
таблица test:
id,name,address,phone,birthday,company,about

таблица table1:
1,2,3,4,5,6

в pma пишу

```
INSERT INTO `test` (test.id,`1`,`2`,`5`,`3`,`6`,`4`)
SELECT uuid(),`1`,`2`,`5`,`3`,`6`,`4` FROM `table2`;
```

Выдает: #1054 - Неизвестный столбец '1' в 'field list'

Comment: вместо номеров столбцов укажите названия

Comment: В таблице нет столбца с именем "1". Возможно вы пытаетесь использовать не ту таблицу

Comment: Novitskiy Denis, спасибо, указал вместо номеров такие же названия, как у другой таблицы, сработало)